# Большое потребление процессорного времени скриптом PHP

Tags: php

На Debian 7.0 вращается в бесконечном цикле демон на PHP.

И вот, в утилите top показывается использование CPU 97-98 %.

Я думаю, что скрипт грузит проц потому что там постоянное обращение к файловой системе, то есть постоянно сканируется каталог на наличие файлов. Если файлы есть - скрипт считывает по одному файл, удаляет его, и выполняет что-то( в основном обращения к внешним API, нет каких то космических вычислений ). Затем следующий файл. В основном, скрипт гоняется вхолостую, то есть файлов нет.

Как оптимизировать? Но при работе со скриптом, срабатывает мгновенно, каких-то 1-3 секунды

Comment: Так никто не пишет код. Вы точно уверены, что Вам нужно проверять постоянно? Вставка паузы на пару секунд погоды не испортит, а вот процессор сильно разгрузит. Но вообще то подобные вещи делают с помощью специальной штуки - [inotify](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.inotify.php). Вы просто говорите файловой системе, что Вы хотите знать и она будет Вас уведомлять (например, о новых файлах или увеличении размера файлов).

Comment: Что-то подобное inotify нужно было. Спасибо!

Comment: Задержка в 1 секунду, в top CPU usage не поднимается выше 0.3% и плюс задержка совсем не чувствуется

Comment: Скрипт крутящийся в цикле без временных ограничений будет сжирать память и процессорное время. Выискивайте альтернативы. Хотя бы тот же Cron

Answer (score 1):

Может, изменить архитектуру? Посмотрите в сторону [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) — это менеджер задач, клиент есть в т.ч. [под php](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.gearman.php).

Вместо мониторинга наличия задач в виде файлов, будем ждать заданий из Gearman.

При появлении нового «задания», помимо создания файла [отправлять задачу](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/gearmanclient.dobackground.php) в Gearman с указанием на файл. Рабочий процесс (worker) так же [крутится в бесконечном цикле](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/gearmanworker.addfunction.php) ожидая новой задачи от Gearman.

Выигрыш:

1. ожидание не грузит CPU;
2. можно выполнять задачи в несколько потоков, если сервер многопроцессорный;
3. можно расширить систему на несколько серверов.